# Visual Maven Dependency Diagram

Tags: maven, build, dependencies

I have a complicated multi-module project. When I run from the command line there are no problems with circular dependency. When I run from [Bamboo](http://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo/overview) I get a circular dependency and the build never ends. It loops around building forever. Does anyone know of a good visual maven dependency graph tool that I can use to see the dependencies. I use intelliJ and this gives me the dependency graph per module but I want to see all the dependencies together for several modules.

Thanks

Comment: Does it need to be visual ? I always use **mvn dependency:tree**(http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html)

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse offers dependency graphing, although I'm not sure if it will aggregate for all modules. Might be worth a try!